# Consume kafka topic and expose a UX using reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, apache-kafka

My goal is to develop react component that will subscribe to kafka topic using rxjs/observable.

I have followed Niels Berglund's [guide](https://nielsberglund.com/2019/06/18/confluent-platform--kafka-for-a-.net-developer-on-windows/) to getting the kafka/Confluent platform up via docker on Windows, and..

I was reading through Guilherme Hermeto's git repo [kafka-observable](https://github.com/ghermeto/kafka-observable#readme) as a way to consume kafka topics.  Has anyone done this?

The part that is unclear was his reference to

```
// assumes getWatchers will execute a network request and returns an observable
const getWatchers = require('./lib/observables/watchers');
```

Comment: This is a just an import. You'll need to use a function that makes a network request

Comment: Kafka clients are typically backend services, by the way, so you wouldn't be consuming it from React

Comment: Updated my question with more details.  That should shed some light on how I am exposing the kafka service (using Confluent's platform).

Comment: It's just Apache Kafka. If you aren't using the Schema Registry, KSQL or other specific Confluent products, then you can use any Kafka Docker image. Anyway, I'm not sure I understand your problem. Have you ran the example code in the README? Are you required to use RxJS because there are plenty of other Kafka Node libraries